# How might the spiderfolk be exploited?

Tags: fantasy-races

I have a fictional race which lives on a small island. The environment on that island is of no use to any of the races on the mainland but is the perfect environment for them. They are a human/spider hybrid kind of thing and have the ability to produce silk, which is prized by the mainland races. They do not have much technological advancement but that is not because they are stupid, they just don't have the resources. They would not stand a chance against an attack from a mainland race although it would be hard to capture/kill all of them. They cannot eat anything except the mosses which grow on their land and the animals eating the moss.

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding, please take a good read at our [help] to understand the kind of question we expect here. You are asking many questions, all of which boil down to "it's your world, it's up to you". Please give us a worldbuilding problem

Comment: Many wars were fought for the possession of Malta, although the wretched island does not have any resources to speak of, much less any kind of *valuable* resources. Guess what, an island might have value even if it is of no use as agricultural land and has no valuable minerals. For example, the island might be desirable as a strategic point to control traffic, or as a resupply base.

Comment: You seem to be asking for story ideas rather than about how to solve a worldbuilding problem as such. Unfortunately that's not what we do here.

Comment: Hi @rainbowcat welcome..WB is very keen on rules and quality, your question *"Will this race be attacked"* is too broad and it would yield too many opinion-based answers. In order to prevent closure of your first topic here, I changed your opening to be a little more specific. I took one of your questions as the main topic. Can't promise this will prevent closure.. if you don't like my changes, you can put your text back, of course..

Comment: Yes, I think that works as an edit. @Goodies

Comment: @ARogueAnt. too bad it invalidated the only existing answer

Comment: @L.Dutch If only we'd been able to close it before the answer was written (or the answerer had waited 'till the question was "finished").

Comment: @L.Dutch how should one go about in such a situation? The answer here is clearly keeping the user from fixing their own question, but asking a new one might result in it being framed as a duplicate as what's been done not long ago in a similar case. Should one try to delete their question? Maybe ask the answering user to kindly delete their answer so the question can be edited? What should be done in such a situation other than forsaking the question and the themes it's asking about altogether?

Comment: @ProjectApex Pose that on meta WB, I'll be there, eating popcorn, occasionally butting-in.

Comment: @rainbowcat please have a look at the tips Willk put in his answer, then work out your story some more.. and if something comes up about the spider people,  *then* ask a NEW question... Ask about their properties, how they would be attacked, how they could prevent attacks.. be specific, ask ONE question. Success !

Comment: @rainbowcat  Why does your w queston menton a "race" when those people are clearly a sepaarate species from any on Earth, and presumably also from other people on their planet.   Using the word "race" for "species" implies that racial differences are as vast as species differences - and history is full of examples of dire results of exaggeratig the importance of racial differences.

Comment: I appreciate your continued interest in salvaging this question. However your most recent edit made this question a lot broader and open ended. Right now you're asking us to brainstorm answers to an open ended question. We're not here to branistorm many equally valid answers. Can you try revising this so that you're asking a more specific question?

Comment: @sphennings I am trying to find a way of making a specific question, but I cannot think of anything. The website won't let me delete the question.

Comment: Hello Rainbow Cat. Let me help you understand why your question has been closed, and why your latest edit doesn't solve the problem. You're suffering from writer's block, meaning that you want ideas to help you past a story problem. Unfortunately, story problems are off-topic here. We answer worldbuilding questions about the rules and systems of your world *independent of any and all stories.* In other words, we can help you design your creatures - but we won't help you use your creatures, because using your creatures is storybuilding.

Comment: BTW, the rules involved here come from the [help/on-topic]. (a) "The goal of the site is to help you build your world, not to tell your story." (b) "If ... you aren’t sure what a character (be it an individual or organization) should do, that is out of scope for the site." How to use (or, in your case, exploit) your creature can be viewed either way: the answer is either based on the circumstances of your story or as a result of character choices. Both are off-topic.

Comment: @rainbowcat It's OK to leave questions be.

Answer (score 3):

**You can make it whatever helps your story.**

1. The spiderfolk are wiped out.
2. The spiderfolk are exploited by commercial powers wanting silk.
3. The spiderfolk are made a protectorate by a powerful country, protecting them from less powerful / reasonable interests, and allowing the spiderfolk (and interests in the powerful country) to profit from their silk.
4. Spiderfolk island is made off limits by a powerful country in the manner of the [Andamanese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_Sentinel_Island) and allowed to do their spiderfolk things without outside interference.

---

Ho hum.  I find it more interesting if

5. Spiderfolk moss turns out to grow like wildfire in the outside world, becoming an invasive species nearly everywhere.  Spiderfolk leave the island and thrive.
6. Spiderfolk carry spiderfolk syphilis which decimates the persons of the outside world.
7. The reasonable philosophy of the spiderfolk turns out to be very popular among persons in the outside world.  The silk is nice, but the spiderfolk religion is really what people want.  Spiderfolk persons are in great demand to head up temples everywhere.  Spiderfolk island is the site of pilgrimages and becomes wealthy as a center of religious teachings.

Comment: You know, "you can make it whatever helps your story" kinda admits that the question violates the [help/on-topic] (The goal of the site is to help you build your world, not to tell your story.) On the other hand, I'm delighted that you included stuff about how to better develop the creatures, which would be beneficial for the OP.

Answer (score 1):

## Everybody gets attacked

A defeated army retreats to an island they can fortify against their pursuers.  Refugees desperate for farmland pile into boats and head to sea.  Pirates scout for a base of operations.  Conniving merchants arrange for a land office to issue them a deed, then they look for any possible way to make their holding pay off.

Your scenario may be reminiscent of [Congo Free State](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congo_Free_State), and you might be interested in working in some elements of that tragedy - the international scientific organization, the nationalist call for colonization, the utopian capitalist model of a state ruled by a corporation.  It is not much of a stretch from rubber to silk, really.